# How to enter C-style comments in cc-mode?

Tags: emacs, comments

I'd prefer to use C-style comments in C++ sources:

```
class Dog {
    string name;                /* The dog's name */
    ...
    void bark();                /* Print messages in Dog's
                                   language */
}
```

However, in cc-mode, when I enter <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, I can only get C++-style comments:

```
class Dog {
    string name;                // The dog's name
    ...
    void bark();                // Print messages in Dog's
                                // language
}
```

Can I set the default comment style in cc-mode to C-style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set the `comment-start` and `comment-end` variables as follows:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq comment-start "/* " comment-end " */")))
```